# Regex to find a word only and following special characters/numbers/dot in dplyr

Tags: regex, dplyr, text, string-matching

Hope this meets you well.
I need to find those rows that contain the term `info` anywhere in the text

1. with no characters before and after
2. following with a dot or any special characters after
3. following with one or more numbers

This is a snapshot of the data that can help

```
df_new <- data.frame(
  text=c('info is given','he is given info. in the class',
               'she needs info2','why not having information',
               'his info# missing', 'info12 and packages are given',
               'parainfo is ready','info. was awarded',
               'meeting is with .info'))
```

```
> df_new
                            text
1                  info is given
2 he is given info. in the class
3                she needs info2
4     why not having information
5              his info# missing
6  info12 and packages are given
7              parainfo is ready
8              info. was awarded
9           meeting is with .info
```

I am using this code but it does not capture all I need :

```
df_new %>%
  mutate(text=tolower(text)) %>%
  mutate(string_detected = as.integer(str_detect(text, "(^|\\s)info(\\s|$)")))
```

Hence, the outcome of interest is:

```
                      text             strings_detected
                  info is given               1
 he is given info. in the class               1   
                she needs info2               1
     why not having information               0
              his info# missing               1
  info12 and packages are given               1
              parainfo is ready               0
              info. was awarded               1 
           meeting is with .info              0
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use something like `\binfo(?=[\d .,#])`. It uses positive lookahead. Add allowed punctuation marks according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should work: `(^| )info([\W\d]|$)`. Note that `\W` will exclude `_`, so if you want to accept `info_`, you should use `(^| )info([\W\d_]|$)` instead.

You can always test your regexes at http://regex101.com